# SignatureDoesNotMatch in Adobe Creative Aviary only in MS Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge, adobecreativesdk

Has anyone else had a problem with the Aviary image editor in Microsoft Edge? The editor works fine in Chrome in my JS web application, but in Edge it opens fine, but clicking save produces a 403:Forbidden error with the following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>ASIAJYVQVY476J5UAPXQ</AWSAccessKeyId><StringToSign>PUT


1459585893
x-amz-acl:public-read
x-amz-security-token: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
/feather-client-files-aviary-prod-us-east-1/2016-04-02/a4aa25e1000943e6a8ad54307b8ab8be.jpg</StringToSign><SignatureProvided> - let's assume this is correct - </SignatureProvided><StringToSignBytes>50 55 54 0a 0a 0a 31 34 35 39 35 38 35 38 39 33 0a 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 61 63 6c 3a 70 75 62 6c 69 63 2d 72 65 61 64 0a 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 73 65 63 75 72 69 74 79 2d 74 6f 6b 65 6e 3a 41 51 6f 44 59 58 64 7a 45 43 6b 61 34 41 4e 4d 4b 76 39 30 32 44 56 68 43 37 71 41 62 38 76 4e 37 6c 2f 63 2b 56 65 43 50 47 36 2b 2b 39 63 36 4c 32 42 62 6c 47 72 5a 56 72 50 2b 76 6a 63 4a 55 4b 62 38 32 7a 69 42 75 70 44 62 32 74 79 70 4c 63 6d 68 4b 63 61 51 66 4a 6e 66 34 6f 50 70 41 54 77 47 48 32 70 42 62 30 72 55 2b 78 46 38 55 36 51 71 4d 41 36 6e 47 31 50 58 6e 48 6c 4e 55 63 41 6c 31 62 76 58 53 69 56 52 62 34 67 36 48 6c 4c 65 53 75 52 6b 5a 6d 74 67 55 77 48 54 5a 48 7a 48 54 35 39 50 49 51 79 67 68 5a 6b 62 65 42 38 50 6d 61 54 39 4d 6a 42 6d 30 52 7a 76 6a 4d 66 54 31 6c 46 57 34 37 39 33 62 72 32 6d 52 58 4e 74 31 73 6a 37 68 77 59 49 74 6e 6e 76 6c 76 2f 38 64 35 6f 53 32 34 49 46 52 74 74 35 58 38 33 36 4b 2b 75 58 62 39 41 4b 46 32 59 6b 44 68 39 6d 48 65 62 44 46 45 6f 54 61 49 6a 78 58 5a 45 2b 45 68 4b 6e 41 32 78 6e 62 5a 56 46 50 78 51 78 33 4a 6d 49 63 36 62 6f 56 52 55 53 37 45 47 7a 68 70 71 42 63 49 52 77 39 34 32 55 4a 30 4d 34 78 69 68 39 64 50 77 4c 69 43 6e 6e 56 32 68 42 2b 6e 7a 66 54 2f 2b 75 4e 55 6f 4b 68 74 70 58 63 73 4e 6b 44 2f 66 75 62 38 56 54 6e 6d 6e 72 48 6a 68 77 62 50 56 51 64 4d 68 6e 2b 61 50 51 38 72 62 58 39 33 54 6a 65 4f 4f 70 7a 63 5a 42 4d 2b 4f 30 33 74 72 39 75 43 59 2f 7a 62 70 65 6f 45 4b 69 71 2f 58 37 55 2b 30 63 30 78 44 59 4d 33 6e 4c 50 75 48 57 33 43 59 37 75 69 73 75 56 48 57 51 66 54 74 61 77 54 2b 4a 56 52 67 2b 62 59 69 53 76 4e 65 7a 53 41 55 36 45 32 36 2b 50 45 58 45 54 54 71 52 55 2b 62 4a 66 43 39 48 48 69 69 30 52 2b 55 76 4b 6a 34 35 34 41 70 63 37 75 55 6b 49 71 36 73 46 6e 35 2b 39 4f 56 67 52 64 78 4c 53 76 4e 6c 4a 47 38 36 66 6a 69 6f 6c 78 42 43 37 50 62 4a 72 52 30 59 7a 49 64 38 64 54 2b 5a 4c 31 49 43 38 49 72 58 49 30 6c 45 35 71 46 33 68 39 6d 49 46 66 59 51 42 50 43 4d 30 6d 71 38 77 66 54 37 39 65 5a 4e 61 46 6e 58 63 58 63 65 68 37 30 61 72 52 58 52 4a 4f 31 47 75 63 53 31 73 75 63 73 69 5a 45 59 65 76 63 4c 53 74 58 78 74 68 58 4f 71 56 49 67 39 76 48 39 74 77 55 3d 0a 2f 66 65 61 74 68 65 72 2d 63 6c 69 65 6e 74 2d 66 69 6c 65 73 2d 61 76 69 61 72 79 2d 70 72 6f 64 2d 75 73 2d 65 61 73 74 2d 31 2f 32 30 31 36 2d 30 34 2d 30 32 2f 61 34 61 61 32 35 65 31 30 30 30 39 34 33 65 36 61 38 61 64 35 34 33 30 37 62 38 61 62 38 62 65 2e 6a 70 67</StringToSignBytes><RequestId>173DDA56B35133C5</RequestId><HostId>JfOujdorxNR/KDPhHfamElEixQqI+B0RFRmXRPThcjhVMq4u7LOHmwXwvkVWh7LtVWLsrPFRbRQ=</HostId></Error>
```

I would assume I put in the wrong signature or other credential, except that it saves fine in Chrome, Firefox, etc.

This is the URL - you'll need to create a free account or sign in with Google/Facebook. https://memorylake.com.au/ - Provide a name and go to the design screen and upload a main photo. I'm sorry I don't have a cleaner example

Comment: Experiencing a very similar issue, although I'm specifically seeing mine in Firefox. Did you figure out what was wrong?